# Not able to read and write data to same Shared Preference from different Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sharedpreferences

I have many `Activities` and `Fragments` in application.I am saving some data in Preference from Activity.I am able to save and read data to same `SharedPreference` in some Activities and Fragments only.I am writing data to particular Preference from `MainActivity` and reading data from same preference in another Activity and Fragment it is possible.But suppose when I am writing data from `ActivityTwo` to same Preference and reading data in `ActivityThree` and other `Fragments` it is not possible.
This is code to save data in Preference from `MainActivity`

```
SharedPreferences prefs,prefs1;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

     prefs=MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
     edit=prefs.edit();
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            saveToken = response.getString("token");
                            edit.putString("token", saveToken);
                            Log.i("Login", saveToken);
                            edit.apply();
                            }
                            catch(JSONException e)
                            {

                            }
```

This is code to  retrieve the Preference value in `Fragment`

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
  prefs=getContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  myToken = prefs.getString("token", "empty");
```

This is code to save data in same Preference from `SecondActivity`

```
 SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
 String saveToken;
  prefs = ActivitySecond.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
               edit = prefs.edit();
             saveToken = response.getString("token");
              edit.putString("token", saveToken);
            edit.apply();
        }
         catch(JSONException e)
         {
         }
```

This is code to retrieve to same value in same other `Fragments` of application

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
  prefs=getContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  myToken = prefs.getString("token", "empty");
```

But this time I am not able to save the value and retrieve the value.How to do this?

Comment: try using `commit()` instead of `apply()` and check if it works

Comment: No.still it has written nothing to preference and not able to retrieve wherever I need it.

Comment: Looks like you haven't initialized `edit` in your `MainActivity`. Are you missing some code?

Comment: I have initialized it and its working fine in MainActivity. The problem is with saving from ActivityTwo

Comment: Are you sure `saveToken` is initialized properly. Looking at your code, it looks like you haven't initialized it.

Comment: Yes.its a string where I am storing value after retrieving it.

Comment: Can you update your code where you are initializing `saveToken` in your `SecondActivity`?

Comment: I m getting that Token in Response which I need to store in Preference.